# Highlight Unique Duplicate Values and sum from a different column

Tags: excel, sum, duplicates, multiple-columns

I have a very large amount of data that includes duplicate values in one column, and another column has values that I need to sum for each of those duplicate values. I have gotten the form cleaned up enough that I can differentiate between different duplicate values easily, and am now going through and manually summing the values in the other column for those duplicates.

My duplicate values are in Column D, and the numbers I need to sum for each of those duplicates in is Column G.

[image]

I've been able to highlight every other duplicate just to make it easier on my eyes, but I can't figure out how to differentiate each unique duplicate value and sum the numbers for that value in column G. You can see that in Column I, I have just literally been going through and summing the values in G for the first set of duplicate values, then the second, and so forth. If there is an easier way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will break it out by chuncks:

```
=IF(AND(H2<>-1,H1<>H2),SUM(G2:INDEX(G2:INDEX(G:G,MATCH(1E+99,G:G)),AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(G2:INDEX(G:G,MATCH(1E+99,G:G)+1))-ROW(G2)+1)/(H2:INDEX(H:H,MATCH(1E+99,G:G)+1)<>H2),1)-1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: You just saved my from doing this manually for over 1000 rows. Thank you so much,

Answer (score 3):

For unsorted data,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B, B2)=COUNTIF(B$2:B2, B2), SUMIFS(D:D, B:B, B2), TEXT(,))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example (it depends on your list being sorted by "Id" column)
The function shown goes in D2 and is then filled down the column

[image]